# Invalid identifier character with file name "insertion"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm new in Go and writing a simple insertion sort but when i change my fileName to "insertion.go" I got error:

> invalid identifier character U+00A0 at insertion.go:2:1

but when I change the filename to anything else it works fine:

**insertion.go**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math/rand"
        "time"
)

func main() {
    slice := generateSlice(20)
    fmt.Println("\n--- Unsorted --- \n\n", slice)
    insertionsort(slice)
    fmt.Println("\n--- Sorted ---\n\n", slice, "\n")
}

func generateSlice(size int) []int {
    slice := make([]int, size, size)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    slice[i] = rand.Intn(999) - rand.Intn(999)
    }
    return slice
}

func insertionsort(items []int) {
    var n = len(items)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        j := i
        for j > 0 {
        if items[j-1] > items[j] {
            items[j-1], items[j] = items[j], items[j-1]
        }
        j = j - 1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know what's the problem with name "insertion"?

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: @user202729 ```go run insertion.go```

Comment: And you change the name accordingly when renaming the file name? Does the run correctly in this case?

Comment: @user202729 yes.

Comment: @Flimzy Surely removing the character helps, but it would be weird if it works fine when the file name is not insertion.go.

Comment: @Flimzy but why it works just when i change the file name? without any change in my code?

Comment: @FatemeFazli: It probably doesn't really work when you change the name. Perhaps your name change just means it's not being compiled at all. Without seeing _exactly what you're doing_, I can't say for sure. But the error message says nothing about the filename, so I have no reason to believe the filename is the problem.

Comment: How do you rename the file? By loading it into your editor and then saving it with a new name? If so, your editor may be removing the weird space.

Comment: @PaulHankin so if my IDE removes it (using vs code) but why it happens again when i change the name to "insertion.go" ?

Comment: @FatemeFazli It could be a weird "feature" of vscode. Try closing the editor, deleting the `insertion.go` file, rename one of the other file to `insertion.go`, and run it.

Comment: Try `diff insertion.go othername.go` and see if the files are different. If they are, it's your editor. If they're the same, it's a weird go bug.

Comment: @PaulHankin Windows use `fc` not `diff`.

Comment: when i rename without vs code it works fine with name "insertion", thank you it's problem with vs code that even i delete the file and new another one with the same name it loads the old file again, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error carefully. Look where the error is occurring: line 2, character 1. That means you have some invalid character in your source file. It's not a problem with the filename. `U+00A0` is a [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), meaning you have an invalid no-break space character in your file, which will appear as invisible.

So apparently, you have the following contents:

```
package main
X
import (
```

Where `X` is an (invisible) NO-BLOCK SPACE (aka `&nbsp;` in HTML speak).

A guess would be that perhaps you copy-pasted this code from a web site, and a `&nbsp;` was erroneously included in the paste.